# Clearing EditText

Tags: android, autocomplete

i want a close button at the end of AutoCompleteTextView so that on click of that button it clears the AutoCompleteTextView. It shouldn't be a button, but something like 'X' mark at the end of AutoCompleteTextView but inside it.Is that possible in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem but with edittext.
Here is my desicion:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:paddingRight="50dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="47dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:layout_width="21dip"
                android:background="@drawable/some_bg"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
            </ImageButton>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

You can place a TextView instead of ImageButton in my example.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the 'X' inside the `AutoCompleteTextView` with `android:drawableRight`, I think. However, finding out if the user clicks on it would be tricky. You might be able to create your own subclass of `AutoCompleteTextView` where you override `onTouchEvent()` and if the event is over your 'X', handle it yourself instead of chaining to the superclass. I have not tried any of this, though, so YMMV.